Trying to use µFR Nano Online wireless NFC RFID reader/writer as external NFC redear
I am trying to use µFR Nano Online wireless NFC RFID reader/writer, as extension of my Galaxy A54's NFC capability. ie. I want to be able to scan NFC tags around my home using 'NFC tools' app without taking my phone out of my pocket. i already have portable power unit to power the device but when I bluetooth the reader to my phone it stores tag UID in keyboard buffer instead of recognising it as a NFC tag.
How do I configure the device to function as I intend?
Cheers

Keyboard emulation in HID mode is a feature of this reader. Also the reader is programmable which means it is not a simply reader. Not sure if this is the correct device for what you want.

CHEERS. Any suggestions for what the correct device might be?

Sorry I have neve bought an NFC reader. Ally my devices have a built-in one.
